# Powershell Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script I wrote to check the contents of a folder and if there is a file with a LastWriteTime older than 20 minutes to notify me.  The problem I am having is when I get the results it is including all of the files in the email body.  How would I write this to get only the latest filename in the email body?

```bsh
$src = 'c:\test'
$sendmail = $false

Get-ChildItem -path $src | ForEach-Object { 
#write-host $_.fullname
$dtdiff = New-TimeSpan ($_.LastWriteTime) $(Get-Date)

if ($dtdiff.TotalMinutes -gt 20){
$strbody=$strbody +$_.fullname+ " Last File Modified at "  +$_.LastWriteTime +"`r`n"
$sendmail=$true
}       
}


#$strbody
 if($sendmail -eq $true){
# Email components
$strFromAddress = "abc@xyz.net"
$strToAddress = "abc@xyz.net"
$strMessageSubject = "REPORT"
$strMessageBody = $strbody
$strSendingServer = "smtp.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$emailSmtpUser = "abc@xyz.net"
$emailSmtpPass = "test123"
# Email objects
$objSMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage              $strFromAddress, $strToAddress, $strMessageSubject, $strMessageBody
$objSMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient(     $strSendingServer, $SMTPPort )
$objSMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$objSMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );
$objSMTPClient.Send($objSMTPMessage)
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by saying latest filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the most actual file: **Edited to remove flaw**

```
Get-ChildItem -path $src | 
  Sort LastWriteTime | 
    Select -last 1 |
      ForEach-Object { 
        #write-host $_.fullname
        $dtdiff = New-TimeSpan ($_.LastWriteTime) $(Get-Date)
        if ($dtdiff.TotalMinutes -gt 20){
          $strbody=$strbody +$_.fullname+ " Last File Modified at "  +$_.LastWriteTime +"`r`n"
          $sendmail=$true
        }       
}
```

Comment: It looks like this will only operate on the oldest file and not the most recent file that is -20 days.

Comment: @lit thanks for the hint, I got different results using `Sort $_.LastWriteTime` and `Sort LastWriteTime` in a folder with only two files. I guess the first is converted to a string.

Comment: I may be reading the OP's question incorrectly, but I think he wants the most recent file that is -20 days. There might be several files in the directory that are more recent than -20 days. It looks like this code will only check for the one most recent file being -20 days.

Comment: The code in the foreach is the original one with TotalMinutes. The pipes only reduce the files to one - if it doesn't match the if no mail is generated.

Comment: The ForEach-Object loop will receive only one (1) file. That file will be the most recent file in the directory. It could be from yesterday or today. The directory might still contain a file from > 20 days ago.

Comment: @lit Yes and the if will check if it is older than 20 mins. I guess Jonathan Alden wants to check if another process is still working properly updating files. So this is a deadman's control/watchdog switch.

Comment: Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

You're appending each filename and its associated timestamp to `$strbody` in that loop. It's doing exactly what you specified.

If you want **only** the latest file that was created in the last 20 minutes, change your `get-childitem/foreach` loop to this:

```bsh
$mostrecentfile = get-childitem -path $src | 
    where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addminutes(-20)} |
    sort-object -property lastwritetime -descending | select-object -first 1
}

if ($mostrecentfile -ne $null) {
$strbody=$_.fullname+ " Last File Modified at "  +$_.LastWriteTime;
$sendmail = $true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get-childitem "c:\temp" -file | where LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-20) |
    Sort lastwritetime -descending  | 
% {

$strFromAddress = "abc@xyz.net"
$strToAddress = "abc@xyz.net"
$strMessageSubject = "REPORT"
$strMessageBody = "Last file modifed '{0}' at {1}" -f $_.fullname, $_.LastWriteTime
$strSendingServer = "smtp.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$emailSmtpUser = "abc@xyz.net"
$emailSmtpPass = "test123"
# Email objects
$objSMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $strFromAddress, $strToAddress, $strMessageSubject, $strMessageBody
$objSMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient($strSendingServer, $SMTPPort )
$objSMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$objSMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );
$objSMTPClient.Send($objSMTPMessage)
$objSMTPClient.Dispose()
break
}
```